# C++ Is there a way to combine this list and map with the same efficiency?

Tags: c++, list, dictionary

I have this code like this right now, example:

```
list <string> names = {"John", "Peter", "Sarah", "Tom"};
map <string, int> age = {{"John", 64}, {"Peter", 32}, {"Sarah", 24}, {"Tom", 25"};
```

I need the age map so I can look up an age against a string name at one point. And I need the name list so I can run through the names in the added sequential order at a different point.

So is there any way to combine this functionality into one so I don't have to repeat the declaration of the name strings, given that the name strings will be identical in both lists. However keeping the exact same efficiency?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [boost multiindex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)?

Comment: You can always store names in a vector (which evidently you need anyway) and then always refer to the index for everything you do, that way you only store the strings once.

Comment: Or define the age `map` first, then extract the keys into `names`?

Comment: Regarding efficiency: `std::list` isn't all that efficient a sequential data structure. It's specified in such a way that it's almost certainly a linked list. You can add and remove easily and quickly, but as soon as you have to iterate through the list, even to find the insertion or removal point, you lose. Sometimes you lose by orders of magnitude. If you just want an ordered list where items are added to the end, usually a `std::vector` works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Person structure and keep a vector of Person and create a map as an index into this vector. If the keys are not unique you should use a multimap. This version is very slow if you need to delete from persons or insert somewhere not at the end of the vector because you have to recreate personIndex.

```
struct Person {
   string name;
   int age;
};
vector<Person> persons;
map<string, size_t> personIndex;

void add( string person, int age )
{
   persons.emplace_back( person, age );
   personIndex[person] = persons.size() - 1;
}
```

Another way is to use a vector of shared_ptr for order and a map to shared_ptr for indexing. This way you get faster access to the element from the index, but it takes more time to find the person in personsOrder (if you'd like to remove for example).

```
vector<shared_ptr<Person>> personsOrder;
map<string, shared_ptr<Person>> persons;

void add( string person, int age )
{
   personsOrder.push_back( make_shared<Person>(person, age) );
   persons[person] = personsOrder.back();
}
```

If you only need the order occasionally, you could store the order in the Person structure and recreate the order vector later.

```
struct Person {
   string name;
   int age;
   size_t insertOrder;
};
map<string, shared_ptr<Person>> persons;

void add( string person, int age )
{
   persons[person] = make_shared<Person>(person, age, persons.size());
}

vector<string> getOrder()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Person>> temp;
    for ( auto& person : persons )
       temp.push_back( person->second );

    sort( begin(temp), end(temp), [](auto&& a, auto&& b) { 
       return a->insertOrder < b->insertOrder;
    }

    vector<string> result;
    for ( auto& person : temp )
       result.push_back( person->name );

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Some good suggestions but I went with 1st suggestion here of the vector to struct. Thanks all.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of options available here.

- Don't store the age with the name, keep 2 different lists and use a shared index to access the name/age pair. Remember with this one you need to be careful that the lists don't have different sizes because that could cause some nasty bugs.
- Create a struct containing name and age, and store those in a container (list, vector, etc).

Comment: Oh, you are correct.  Those have been removed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are never invalidated by altering a `std::map` structure, unless you are removing the same exact element. So you can store them in a `std::vector`, eg:

```
std::map<string, int> ages;
std::vector<decltype(ages)::const_iterator> names;

auto pair = ages.emplace(std::make_pair("foo", 25));
names.push_back(pair.first);

std::cout << names[0]->first << " " << names[1]->second << std::endl;
```